# Facebook Javascript - URL not allowed

Tags: javascript, facebook, url

can someone tell me why I am getting this Error:

> One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It
>   must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a
>   subdomain of one of the App's domains.

At my facebook app I tried some URLs like "example.com", since I do not have a server to upload my stuff yet.

But I have used some App Ids that work for sure and still get the error, so I need to add something to my html stuff?

Thanks for any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the URL of the actual app that you're using to access your facebook app using the API. Even if it is localhost, you need to set the correct URL in order to be able to test.

Check the [FB developers documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#canvas) for more details

Comment: Oh, so I have to add my local path to index.html in app domains at my facebook app? Hm.. this could cause a problem, since I am writing a handy app, thus I can't just say "xx.html", any idea how to solve this? :) thanks btw. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Canvas URL at the end add `/` and if you're using a Tab than the filename must be specified

[image]